Should I replace polybutylene plumbing in my newly purchased house?
It's my first time buying a detached home, and the house seems great except for the fact that the downstairs is all polybutylene plumbing.  The prior owners apparently swapped out all of the upstairs for pex when they renovated, but downstairs remains the same.
I'm thinking I should get ahead of the problem and replace all that polybutylene before I move in, but my agent thinks I'm being overly paranoid and "if it ain't broke, don't fix it".  But from what I've been reading online, it sounds like this stuff has a few different and equally unpleasant failure scenarios that I'd like to avoid - and it's already about 30 years old right now. (house was built in 1993)
Am I being paranoid?  Is the fact that it's been in place for 30 years a sign that perhaps it won't actually be a problem, or is it a time bomb waiting to go off?

30 years for PolyB means it has had a good run. If this is a long term buy and you have the time to allow for the renovation before occupancy, it is worth considering.

Good deal - yeah, I had a similar feeling.  I kept reading online that it generally lasted 10-15 years, so it was a little shocking to me to see it still there.  But it's hard for me to tell whether the info I've been reading is extreme or not, I know so little about plumbing.  I get the feeling I'll sleep better at night if I get rid of it.

I had poly pipe installed in my house, a 1989 build, before it was banned. I found out later the reason it was banned beacuse it was the chlorine added in the water conditioners or a part of the conditioning system, that degraded the pipes to cause them to fail.

Yeah, I've been reading the same.  We get our water from the public line, and it's got chlorine so I get the feeling I'll be better off pulling it out.  But it's hard for me to say for sure because it appears to have held up for 30 years at this point.  I think I'm not going to take my chances.
